Blinking cursor after graphical login. Desktop takes > 5min to appear. Diagnostic info needed
PC running 22.04, dual boot with Windows. Boot sequence runs through fine from grub menu to Ubuntu graphical login screen. After entering my password the screen goes black and stays that way for over five minutes. There is a flashing white cursor at the top left of the screen. Then the desktop appears and I can start working.
The desktop has always taken > 10s to display after graphical login. The only thing that has changed yesterday is my reinstallation of the firefox snap.
I have used systemd-analyze time (17s) but this stops giving information after reaching "graphical.target". How can I diagnose what is happening while the screen is black?
EDIT:
I have x11 running.
Tried systemctl status display-manager.service.
Output:
Jul 20 12:07:48 user-desktop systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
Jul 20 12:07:49 user-desktop gdm-launch-environment][819]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): ses>
Jul 20 12:11:48 user-desktop gdm-password][1629]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Jul 20 12:11:48 user-desktop gdm-password][1629]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Jul 20 12:11:48 user-desktop gdm-password][1629]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for use>
Jul 20 12:11:48 user-desktop gdm-password][1629]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unl>
Jul 20 12:25:13 user-desktop gdm3[791]: Gdm: Child process -927 was already dead.```


X11 or Wayland? [edit] in to your question. Also look at this ubuntubuzz post

Thanks @graham. Have looked at the post. These are all general performance improvements which I'll try once I've resolved the black screen on login :)

for completeness, log out of X11 and log back in with Wayland to see if the issue persists.

There is no cog on the login screen. Possibly because I have an Nvidia card. So not possible to login with Wayland  atm

Will try swopping to Nouveau when I have some more time PS The cursor actually doesn't blink. So I thought the screen was frozen and hard rebooted a couple of times

systemd-analyze blame | less && dmesg | less check to see where the longest time is spent, and if there are any fails, errors or warnings

"So not possible to login with Wayland" you may be interested in this AU Q&A then

@Hannu Thanks, this only shows processes up to the graphical screen and not beyond. All looks ok with only these taking loner than 1s: 3.737s snapd.seeded.service 3.687s NetworkManager-wait-online.service 3.279s snapd.service 3.050s plymouth-quit-wait.service 2.405s dev-sda9.device 2.381s dev-sda8.device 2.305s cups.service 2.248s udisks2.service 2.136s containerd.service 1.099s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-f21a233e\x2d970f\x2d4845\x2d96d0\x2d8306960c4918.service 1.063s networkd-dispatcher.service 1.037s boot.mount

@graham Thanks for this reference - I made those changes to 61-gdm.rules, but still do not get the cog with option to use Wayland. Changed driver to Nouveau and that did not help. Changed back to Nvidia, no change either. For reference, I add my latest ouput from systemctl status display-manager.service:  `Jul 21 16:17:21 user-desktop gdm-password][1635]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
Jul 21 16:30:48 user-desktop gdm3[774]: Gdm: Child process -1357 was already dead.```

Couldn't solve this. Bought another SSD and installed Ubuntu there. So Windows runs on the old one by itself. Purring along. No HDD thrashing
